# Template Parse Error: Problem with undefined values and ngIf with custom Pipe

Tags: angular

I am currently having a problem with implementing a conditional button on my webpage. My pipe is working already, but I can't seem to get the conditionals to work. My userInfo is undefined until my MongoDB gets the results. I get the following error,

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined (" "end center" >
```

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0cJf.png)

New user sorry about formatting.

Comment: Please provide actual code and not a screenshot

Comment: Hi, please refrain from posting images of your code but instead paste it into your question directly. This makes it easier to understand what's going on and more likely that the question is going to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for this is to add `*ngIf` to your `<mat-card-content>`

Then that component won't try to render until data is present, and properties are accessed.

If you need to display other data in the card that isn't dependent on `userInfo`, you can wrap the elements/components that depend on `userInfo` with `<ng-container>` and put the if statement there:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="userInfo">
    ...
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this comment from your template:

```html
<!-- <div *ngIf={{userInfo.usertypeid | isAdmin}} -->
```

The `ngIf` syntax is wrong and, even if it's commented, angular compiler will try to evaluate it.